# How do I turn off teasers?

Tags: nodes

I have a Drupal 7 site and on some pages, such as the front page. I don't want a list of teasers to show; I just want a Basic Page to show.  How do I do this?

I have looked in content types, blocks, and in the edit screens of the content items themselves, to no avail!

Comment: you can set your default front page in admin/config/system/site-information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different ways/options to solve your issue.

**Option 1:** 
Create a page node and then set node URL as default front page in `admin/config/system/site-information`

**Option 2:**
Create a view page using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and set the page url as default front page (same as previous option).

**Option 3:**
Download and Enable [Empty Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_front_page) module and then locate any block you want in the content region.

Comment: he asked a question how to disable teaser, he already created the front page

Comment: @Bala the title of the question says something and description says something else "I just want a Basic Page to show"

Comment: @Bala Since the question is about teasers shown in the front page, this is the right answer.